# Safari window resize CSS issue

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a portfolio site here: www.mrliger.com. When I open the site in any browser apart from Safari and resize the browser window, the menu at the top of the page changes styles as desired. However when I resize the browser window in Safari, the header restylesto how I desire but when enlarging the window again to full size the header becomes stacked... Have no idea what is causing this. Could someone please take a look and advise?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the problem it seems to be working for me!

Comment: strange, im running Safari 5.1.7. What about you?

Comment: 8.0.6, that might have something to do with it

Comment: is my version very old? (if so i wont bother fixing it)

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 is 3 years old. You shouldn't be using it any more; it has very little in common with modern browsers. Yeah, I know, there are no newer Safaris on Windows, but that doesn't change anything; testing with that one is a waste of time. (Well, you can, if you're thorough, test your website in multiple versions of browsers; I have a VirtualBox here with IE8 and Firefox 3.6 for that very purpose, but your primary concern should be today's browsers. Make sure your site runs there; then check if it doesn't break too badly in the older ones.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will forget it altogether!

Comment: @BenLiger By the way, you have a lot of errors in your code. `<link>`s outside of the `<head>`, <li>` in `<a>` etc. If you correct all of them, maybe it will run better in older browsers!